# Add Multiple Levels of Input Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a product page that will input a cost, quantity and spit out the cost after taking the product of the 2.

I have figured it out here http://jsfiddle.net/61tch8md/ for the most part (I believe) but the issue I have is that the user can add multiple lines and each line needs to only add the quantity and cost of the fields on that row. Right now when I add additional rows, the first line will control the price for all the lines.

**HTML**

```
<table class="order-details">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Description of Work" class="wei-add-field description 1" name="product-1-description" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="QTY" class="wei-add-field quantity 1" name="product-1-quantity" /></td>
        <td><span class="wei-price">$</span><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Unit Price" class="wei-add-field unit-price 1" name="product-1-price"/></td>
        <td><span class="wei-price-total"></span></td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="wei-add-service"><a href="#" class="button-secondary wei-add-service-button">Add Item</a></div>
```

**JavaScript / Jquery**

```
jQuery( "tr" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = jQuery( ".unit-price" ).val();
    var value2 = jQuery( ".quantity" ).val();
    var total = value * value2;

    jQuery( ".wei-price-total" ).text( total );
  })
  .keyup()

var counter = 2;
jQuery('a.wei-add-service-button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Description of Work" class="wei-add-field description" name="product-' + 
        counter + '-description" /></td><td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="QTY" class="wei-add-field quantity" name="product-' + 
        counter + '-quantity" /></td><td><span class="wei-price">$</span><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Unit Price" class="wei-add-field unit-price" name="product-' + 
        counter + '-price"/></td><td><span class="wei-price-total">$49.99</span></td><td><a href="#" class="remove">remove</a></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.order-details').append(newRow);
});


jQuery('table.order-details').on('click','tr a',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
jQuery(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code so it selects the inputs in the row that the `keyup` happened on.

```
jQuery('table.order-details').on("keyup", "tr", function() {
    var row = jQuery(this);
    var value = jQuery( ".unit-price", row ).val();
    var value2 = jQuery( ".quantity", row ).val();
    var total = value * value2;

    jQuery( ".wei-price-total", row ).text( total );
  });
```

Comment: I updated it, and now it only edits the first line. When I add additional rows, they do not update at all http://jsfiddle.net/61tch8md/1/

Comment: You need to use event delegation to bind the handler to dynamically-added rows. Like you do for the function that removes rows. I've updated the answer to show how to code that.